# 401 on OData call to D365FO

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, odata, microsoft-dynamics, php-curl

I'm trying to make an OData call to retrieve a D365FO data entity.
https://[root_URL]/data/CostGroups
When logged into D365FO in my browser, this call works.

- I'm working in PHP.
- I've registered my app in Azure Active Directory.
- I've provided my app the https://erp.dynamics.com/Connector.FullAccess API permission.
- I've registered my app in D365FO with a user that has admin privileges (the same user used for the successful browser call).
- I am able to acquire an authentication token.

  - Its "aud" field is "https://erp.dynamics.com"
  - Its "appid" field matches that of the app's Azure AD registration
  - Its "roles" field includes only "Connector.FullAccess"
- I'm using curl in PHP to make the OData GET request. I use the URL listed above and my headers are

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'OData-MaxVersion: 4.0',
    'OData-Version: 4.0',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->accessToken
]);
```

Response is "401 Unauthorized"

Does anyone know what's going wrong or how I can find more information about the failure? Is there anywhere in D365FO I can look for logs of my attempts?

Comment: What `flow` do you have perform ? I suspect you use the **AuthorizationCode** instead of **AccessToken** for logging see inside the Azure App there a section for logs.

Comment: I'm using service-to-service for a web application. I get my access token by passing my Client ID and Client Secret to
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token

Comment: In the Azure app (portal.azure.com) I've found an "Activity log" and an "Operation log (classic)" The first has no records. The second takes me to a "Not found" error page.

Comment: Have you registered your external application in D365 FO **System administration** > **Setup** > **Azure Active Directory applications**?

Comment: @AllenWu, yes, I have registered the app in D365 FO. I assigned it to a user that has admin privileges and is also the same account used when I successfully made the OData call in a web browser.

Comment: Have you tested it with the same headers in Postman? What is the result? Still the 401 error? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test#prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resource` seems to be incorrect. It should be the base URL of the instance without the trailing '/'.

Your "aud" field is `https://erp.dynamics.com`. In this case, it should be your [root URL]. Like this:

[image]

Check your `resource` when you post a request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant ID]/oauth2/token`.

Comment: Thank you. You're correct that my "aud" field contained the wrong value.
I removed `scope: https://erp.dynamics.com/.default` from my token request POST headers and added `resource: [BaseURL]`. At first, I received `400 Bad Request`. I removed `v2.0` from my token request URL (I now realize the URL I listed above was not what I was actually using) and everything is working.

Comment: Yes. `resource` is for v1.0 and `scope` is for v2.0. Glad to know this issue is resolved:)